Android phone does not show up on file manager when cable is connected
Android phone does not show up on file manager when cable is connected.
Thunar is my file manager.
I am using Ubuntu-Mate.
It used to work ?
My phone is a samsung a25.
Can someone help me?

Have you tested a different USB cable? have you checked Windows device manager if a device appears when you connect your phone? Is the phone unlocked (enter pin after reboot on lock screen)?

"File manager"? Linux? macOS? Windows? Atari? Need more info.

Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself. Consider posting it as a proper answer since self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged. Thanks.

@Andrew T. Thanks for your positive attitude. You encourage me while a few look for ways to complain.

It was a bad cable. Replacing the cable connecting an android phone to my desktop computer running Ubuntu Mate 24.04 was successful in allowing the transfer of files.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
